# How to find a memory leak in javac task

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, javac

I recently did a good amount of code change (due to a 3rd party library upgrade) in my java project.
It resulted in my ant compilation task to go outofmemory (Heap space - old generation).

I was using 1G of Xmx earlier, I have to use 2G now for successful compilation.
I have profiled the javac process, but I do not get much insight.
I have enabled verbose output and I find that it goes out of memory while loading the classes.

Is there a way to find if there is a memory leak in a javac program?

```
javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.class)]]
javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.class)]]
javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchemaType.class)]]
javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementDecl.class)]]
javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.class)]]
```

javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Dev\jdks\jdk7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.class)]]

```
javac]
javac]
javac] The system is out of resources.
javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
javac] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$ImportScope.makeEntry(Scope.java:515)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.enter(Scope.java:219)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.enter(Scope.java:201)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$StarImportScope.importAll(Scope.java:540)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.importAll(MemberEnter.java:147)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:522)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:459)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:401)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:876)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:421)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:821)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:491)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:469)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:929)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:824)
javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:439)
```

Comment: There are java memory profilers for this purpose such as JProfiler, YourKit Profiler. But if you find a memory leak, what do you want to do about?

Comment: (1) the likelihood of you finding a memory leak in `javac` is vanishingly small; it's used by tens of thousands of people every day. (2) without more information (such as the Ant task that you're executing and the output from your script) it is impossible for anybody to help you find your *real* problem.

Comment: @kdgregory - I am just running a javac ant task with source directory that has my java classes.

Comment: @Codo - If it is not memory leak, Could it be a wrong jar in my classpath.

Comment: It's unliekly to be related to an invalid jar in the classpath. The compiler would complain or ignore it. As @PeterLawrey points out, it's probably just a huge memory consumption for the duration of the compilation.

Comment: It looks like you're processing generated JAXB files. How complex are those files? It is possible that the generated file causes a problem in the compiler, or (as other people have said) that they're simply complex enough to require more memory.

Comment: For what it's worth, "The Scope class is a container for symbols which provides efficient access to symbols given their names." (from the [JDK7 source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/)). This implies to me that the file being compiled has too many symbols within a given scope for the available memory. And since it's a JAXB file, I suspect that there are too many potential elements/attributes in the underlying schema. All of which is to say: you either need to trim your schema or increase compiler memory.

Comment: @kdgregory - I find this weird because all I did is a log4j upgrade from 1.x version to 2.5 and the memory usage for javac went from 1000m to 2000m. It works with 1350m too, provided I use the G1 GC instead of the default GC of Java 1.7 which I guess is parallel GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `javac` just needs more memory than the default.

The more complex the code, the more memory it uses. This is unlikely to be a bug or because you are using the wrong JAR.

I would make sure you are using the latest update in case it's an issue which has been fixed but this is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: Never found the memory leak reason on the compile task. just reduced the usage by switching the GC from default ParallelGC to G1 and it brought down the memory usage by about 40 percent. Accepting this answer and closing this question. Thanks @Peter Lawrey